# Déjà vu or actual memory?

Tags: the-dark-tower

I am rereading The Dark Tower series and this text caught by eye.

> It was a haunting line. For a moment the gunslinger felt mixed feelings of nostalgia and fear, **stitched in with an eerie feeling of déjà vu, and he thought: I dreamed this. Or I was here before.** If so, when? Not Mejis. No, not there. He shook the feeling off. The audience—perhaps twenty-five all told—had become dead silent. Every eye touched the preacher-woman.
>
> ***The Gunslinger, Chapter 12***

Is it his memory coming back or just  a sense of déjà vu?

Comment: @bob1 I agree, its just that these things happen only in the first book. So it makes me think that some of his memories are still there.

Comment: @bob1 Your commentary contains the biggest spoiler one can have. Please convert it into an answer, by using `>!` to hide the relevant pieces of text.

Comment: I've deleted my comment and added it as a more complete answer in response to @MatemáticosChibchas comment.

Answer (score 2):

In response to @MatemáticosChibchas comment I have made this an answer.

> The Dark Tower series is cyclical in nature - Roland is having visions of things that have happened to him in past lives or perhaps past cycles of "Mid-World" or even in "parallel universes". Note that this is a cycle after the manner of a repeating event not a [literary cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literary_cycle) (though it could also be considered one of those). This is also revealed in the `Coda` chapter in the book, during which King urges the reader to close the book and imagine the ending themselves. In this chapter Roland finally opens a door and finds himself back at the beginning of `The Gunslinger`.

> King's work on this series is heavily influenced by a number of works of literature including the fables of `King Arthur` and the `Lord of the Rings` both of which have elements that indicate a repeating or cyclical nature to the universe - in King Arthur it is that he lies sleeping until Britain needs him again. In the LoTR universe, which is heavily influenced by Norse mythology, the world is reborn after [`Dagor Dagorath`](https://atolkienistperspective.wordpress.com/2014/01/28/the-tale-of-the-dagor-dagorath/) ([`Ragnarok`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ragnar%C3%B6k) in Norse mythology).